# Apache is adding header to images resulting in corrupting images

Tags: docker, apache, kubernetes

I'm dockerizing a laravel application, my image is based on an apache image, this is being hosted in AKS, where I'm mounting azure files with images share inside /public/images, the problem is apache would add header inside the image resulting in corrupting the images

[image]

even if I exec inside the pod itself and try curl localhost, I get the same problem so I'm sure it's not a problem with routing or my ingress

```
    FROM php:7.3-apache

#install all the system dependencies and enable PHP modules 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev openssl
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mbstring 
RUN apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev && \
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
# RUN apt-get install wget
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install curl -y

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

#set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

#change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

#change the web_root to laravel /var/www/html/public folder
#RUN sed -i -e "s/html/html\/public/g" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
COPY vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN echo "EnableSendfile off" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf


# enable apache module rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

#copy source files and run composer
COPY . $APP_HOME

# install all PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction


#change ownership of our applications
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data $APP_HOME
```

next using regular deployment yaml file to push this to kubernetes with the following Volume mounts:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: sessions
  mountPath: /var/www/html/storage/framework/sessions
- name: cache
  mountPath: /var/www/html/storage/framework/cache
- name: views
  mountPath: /var/www/html/storage/framework/views
- name: images
  mountPath: /var/www/html/public/images
```

volumes:

- name: sessions
  azureFile:
  secretName: appmnt
  shareName: sessions
  readOnly: false
- name: cache
  azureFile:
  secretName: appmnt
  shareName: cache
  readOnly: false
- name: views
  azureFile:
  secretName: appmnt
  shareName: views
  readOnly: false
- name: images
  azureFile:
  secretName: appmnt
  shareName: images
  readOnly: false

now the problem is if i try to access a static file from images folder, by example using a url like "https://www.somedomain.com/images/somefile.png"

the file will be download but apache will attach the above headers to the content resulting in corruption.

the web applications work perfectly fine, except for any files inside the volume mounts.

if i do "kubectl exec -it podname -- bash" and browse the files i can see the volume mounts are working fine, also if i try to upload files from the application interface, the file gets written in the write way inside the folder, only problem is with browsing the file.

Comment: Can you share more details about the image and the code that is serving the images. It's not ingress since it's same inside the pod, and routing will never add headers. It's unclear which headers are the problem and what is the expected behavior.

Comment: Done, i have put more details, expected behavior is for images  to be downloaded or browsed with corruption

Comment: It's not Docker or Kubernetes problem. I assume it would be the apache configuration or the code itself. Can you check vhost.conf and compare it to [this article](https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/steps-for-configuring-laravel-on-apache-http-server/). Also compare the steps you are taking

Comment: jordanvrtanoski may be right. Is it possible for you to share your `vhost.conf` file with us ?

Comment: Just a side note: instead of calling all those `apt-get`, `pecl`, `docker-php-ext-install` commands, what about using https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We fixed the issue, simply in the vhost.conf, we needed to turn off EnableMMAP

```
EnableMMAP off
```

Comment: This resolved the same error for me when switching a vagrant build from virtualbox to hyper-v with no other changes.